# How to return anonymous type as json in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

This is my function.

```
    function reqQuoteFile(_url) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: _url,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if(data["itemsNotSupportedWarning"] != '')
                {
                    alert(data["itemsNotSupportedWarning"]);
                    //more code...
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

It calling this action

```
public ActionResult ExportQuote(string projectNumber)
{
 //more code here...

 return Json(new 
               { quoteFileName = _quoteFileName, 
                 itemsNotSupportedWarning = _itemsNotSupportedWarning 
            });
}
```

**_quoteFileName** and **_itemsNotSupportedWarning** are strings.

When I run the code in debug mode, the ajax is calling the action. However, after the action executes, the alert popup doesn't show up.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are returning an anonymous type correctly. BUT, you need add `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`

e.g.

```
public ActionResult ExportQuote(string projectNumber)
{
 //more code here...

 return Json(new 
               { quoteFileName = _quoteFileName, 
                 itemsNotSupportedWarning = _itemsNotSupportedWarning 
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Also, this isnt necessary, but you can change `data["itemsNotSupportedWarning"]` to `data.itemsNotSupportedWarning` to access the json properties:

```
//change to data.itemsNotSupportedWarning
if (data.itemsNotSupportedWarning != '') {

    alert(data.itemsNotSupportedWarning); 
    //more code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that a typo there ??

```
date["itemsNotSupportedWarning"]
```

instead of data you are typing date